# How to evaluate a text to multiple texts? VB

Tags: .net, vba, if-statement

As I can compare several values with an "if" visual basic?

```
If TextDisplay.Text = {"/","*","+","-"} Then

End If
```

which would be the correct way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not that good in Visual Basic, but I guess you need `Contains`:

```
Dim AllowedCharacters() As String = {"/", "*", "+", "-"}
If AllowedCharacters.Contains(TextDisplay.Text) Then
    'do something
End If
```

Comment: This really only works if you want to check TestDisplay.Text to only be one of those values. For example, if TextDisplay.text == "/Help", this check will fail as "/Help" is not in the AllowedCharacters set. You'll probably want something more along the lines of what Steve answered if you're trying to check if _any_ of the "AllowedCharacters" are in TextDisplay.Text.

Answer (score 2):

If you are searching just chars and not entire words then the string class has already the method required

```
If TextDisplay.Text.IndexOfAny(New Char() {"/"c,"*"c,"+"c,"-"c}) > -1 Then
    .....
End If
```

IndexOfAny returns the index of the first char that matches the provided list. (so you need to test for -1 because zero is a valid index)

Also  note the appended letter `c` to denote a char constant.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a calculator so assuming you only want to test for an exact single character match you could simply:

```
If ("/*+-".IndexOf(TextDisplay.Text) > 0) Then
```

Or VBA:

```
If InStr(1, "/*+-", TextDisplay.Text) > 0 Then
```

(You need to check for an empty input string as well)